# How to create C# executable without Exe-Container

Tags: c#, mono, portable-executable, coff

Can I produce a executable for linux using the language C# that does not use microsoft windows exe file format?

I know that mono can read the IL instructions out of a windows executable, but I am curious if this is also possible using an unix elf file (standard executables like produced by gcc or other compilers).

I still want to use mono (or something like this) but dont want the PE Header in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a bundle which will incorporate the .net framework and be a real Linux executable with mkbundle, but beware, it can have license problems with Novell.

Read this, the Bundle section: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/